# How do I send a character from a string that is NOT a letter or a number to the end of the string?

Tags: python

I am doing a Pig Latin code in which the following words are supposed to return the following responses:

```
"computer" == "omputercay"
"think" == "inkthay"
"algorithm" == "algorithmway"
"office" == "officeway"
"Computer" == "Omputercay"
"Science!" == "Iencescay!"
```

However, for the last word, my code does not push the '!' to the end of the string. What is the code that will make this happen?

All of them return the correct word apart from the last which returns "Ience!Scay!"

```
def pigLatin(word):
    vowel = ("a","e","i","o","u")

    first_letter = word[0]
    if first_letter in vowel:
        return word +'way'

    else:
        l = len(word)
        i = 0
        while i < l:
            i = i + 1
            if word[i] in vowel:
                x = i
                new_word = word[i:] + word[:i] + "ay"

                if word[0].isupper():
                    new_word = new_word.title()

                return new_word
```

Comment: Your code is treating the exclamation point as a letter. An exclamation point is an ending punctuation mark, meaning, it will always come at the end of a word. Consider ways in which you could get only the word to modify, leaving out the exclamation point. You could then apply the punctuation mark after the string construction has been completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, how about you check if the word contains an exlamation point `!` at the end and if it does just remove it and when you are done add it back. So instead of `return`ing just check place `!` at the end (if you discovered it does at the beggining).

```
def pigLatin(word):
    vowel = ("a","e","i","o","u")

    first_letter = word[0]
    if first_letter in vowel:
        return word +'way'

    else:
        hasExlamation = False

        if word[-1] == '!':
            word = word[:-1] # removes last letter
            hasExlamation = True

        l = len(word)
        i = 0
        while i < l:
            i = i + 1
            if word[i] in vowel:
                x = i
                new_word = word[i:] + word[:i] + "ay"

                if word[0].isupper():
                    new_word = new_word.title()

                break # do not return just break out of the `while` loop
        if hasExlamation:
            new_word += "!" # same as new_word = new_word + "!"
        return new_word
```

That way it does not treat `!` as a normal letter and the output is `Iencescay!`. You can of course do this with any other character similarly

```
specialCharacters = ["!"] # define this outside the function

def pigLatin():
    # all of the code above
    if word in specialCharacters:
        hasSpecialCharacter = True
    # then you can continue the same way
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions to the rescue. A regex pattern with word boundaries will make your life much easier in this case. A word boundary is exactly what it sounds like - it indicates the start- or end of a word, and is represented in the pattern with `\b`. In your case, the `!` would be such a word boundary. The "word" itself consists of any character in the set `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or underscore, and is represented by `\w` in the pattern. The `+` means, one or more `\w` characters.

So, if the pattern is `r"\b\w+\b"`, this will match any word (consisting of any of `a-zA-Z0-9_`), with leading or succeeding word boundaries.

```
import re

pattern = r"\b\w+\b"
sentence = "computer think algorithm office Computer Science!"

print(re.findall(pattern, sentence))
```

Output:

```
['computer', 'think', 'algorithm', 'office', 'Computer', 'Science']
>>>
```

Here, we're using `re.findall` to get a list of all substrings that matched the pattern. Notice, no whitespace or punctuation is included.

---

Let's introduce `re.sub`, which takes a pattern to look for, a string to look through, and another string with which to replace any match it finds. Instead of a replacement-string, you can instead pass in a function. This function must take a match object as a parameter, and must return a string with which to replace the current match.

```
import re

pattern = r"\b\w+\b"
sentence = "computer think algorithm office Computer Science!"

def replace(match):
    return "*" * len(match.group())

print(re.sub(pattern, replace, sentence))
```

Output:

```
******** ***** ********* ****** ******** *******!
>>>
```

That's just for demonstration purposes.

---

Let's change gears for a second:

```
from string import ascii_letters as alphabet
print(alphabet)
```

Output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>>>
```

That's handy for creating a string containing only consonants:

```
from string import ascii_letters as alphabet

consonants = "".join(set(alphabet) ^ set("aeiouAEIOU"))
print(consonants)
```

Output:

```
nptDPbHvsxKNWdYyrTqVQRlBCZShzgGjfkJMLmFXwc
>>>
```

We've taken the difference between the set of all alpha-characters and the set of only vowels. This yields the set of only consonants. Notice, that the order of the characters it not preserved in a set, but it doesn't matter in our case, since we'll be effectively treating this string as a set - testing for membership (if a character is in this string, it must be a consonant. The order does not matter).

---

Let's take advantage of this, and modify our pattern from earlier. Let's add two capturing groups - the first will capture any leading consonants (if they exist), the second will capture all remaining alpha characters (consonants or vowels) before the terminating word boundary:

```
import re
from string import ascii_letters as alphabet
consonants = "".join(set(alphabet) ^ set("aeiouAEIOU"))

pattern = fr"\b([{consonants}]*)(\w+)\b"
word = "computer"

match = re.match(pattern, word)
if match is not None:
    print(f"Group one is \"{match.group(1)}\"")
    print(f"Group two is \"{match.group(2)}\"")
```

Output:

```
Group one is "c"
Group two is "omputer"
>>>
```

As you can see, the first group captured `c`, and the second group captured `omputer`. Separating the match into two groups will be useful later when we construct the pig-latin translation. We can get even cuter by naming our capturing groups. This isn't required, but it will make things a bit easier to read later on:

```
pattern = fr"\b(?P<prefix>[{consonants}]*)(?P<rest>\w+)\b"
```

Now, the first capturing group is named `prefix`, and can be accessed via `match.group("prefix")`, rather than `match.group(1)`. The second capturing group is named `rest`, and can be accessed via `match.group("rest")` instead of `match.group(2)`.

---

Putting it all together:

```
import re
from string import ascii_letters as alphabet
consonants = "".join(set(alphabet) ^ set("aeiouAEIOU"))

pattern = fr"\b(?P<prefix>[{consonants}]*)(?P<rest>\w+)\b"
sentence = "computer think algorithm office Computer Science!"

def to_pig_latin(match):
    rest = match.group("rest")
    prefix = match.group("prefix")

    result = rest + prefix

    if len(prefix) == 0:
        # if the 'prefix' capturing group was empty
        # the word must have started with a vowel
        # so, the suffix is 'way'
        result += "way"
        # that also means we need to check if the first character...
        # ... (which must be in 'rest') was upper-case.
        if rest[0].isupper():
            result = result.title()
    else:
        result += "ay"
        if prefix[0].isupper():
            result = result.title()

    return result

print(re.sub(pattern, to_pig_latin, sentence))
```

Output:

```
omputercay inkthay algorithmway officeway Omputercay Iencescay!
>>>
```

That was the verbose version. The definition of `to_pig_latin` can be shortened to:

```
def to_pig_latin(match):
    rest = match.group("rest")
    prefix = match.group("prefix")
    return (str, str.title)[(prefix or rest)[0].isupper()](rest + prefix + "way"[bool(prefix):])
```

Comment: Probably you already know about it but I think using raw strings for regex patterns makes them more readable. I wish I had more upvotes :) Great post!

Comment: @Asocia Thanks! I agree, though there is no syntax that allows you to combine an f-string with a raw string, and I try to avoid using `str.format`, if I can :)

Comment: Actually there is. Just prefix your string with `r` :) Like `fr'...'` or `rf'...'`. Order doesn't matter and it works as you expected.

Comment: @Asocia Whaaaaaat! I had no idea. Thanks!